# Pandas division and summation mapped over each row

Tags: python, pandas

So this one is a bit confusing to explain, so I'm hoping the example will help. What I'm trying to do is get the contribution that each row in a DataFrame adds or takes away from a weighted average. To do this, I need a column that shows what the sum() of all the rows would be if we took the value multiplied by the weight divided by the (sum of weights - this row's weight). I'm wondering the most efficient way to do this.

The best way to explain is coding:

```
In [54]: ex_dic = {1: {'Weight': 100, 'X': 10}, 2: {'Weight': 200, 'X': 20}, 3: {'Weight': 500, 'X': 35}}

In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ex_dic,orient='index')

In [60]: df['Mult'] = df['X'] * df['Weight']

In [62]: df['SumWeight'] = df['Weight'].sum()

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
    X  Weight   Mult  SumWeight
1  10     100   1000        800
2  20     200   4000        800
3  35     500  17500        800
```

So now we have the DataFrame. Now I want to add a new column with the values below, but in the most efficient way we can.

So here is what I would want for row 1, taking out the 100 for it's weight.

```
In [69]: (df['Mult'] / (df['SumWeight'] - 100)).sum()
Out[69]: 32.142857142857146
```

Row 2, taking out the 200 for it's weight

```
In [70]: (df['Mult'] / (df['SumWeight'] - 200)).sum()
Out[70]: 37.5
```

Row 3, taking out the 500 for it's weight

```
In [71]: (df['Mult'] / (df['SumWeight'] - 500)).sum()
Out[71]: 75.0
```

So I'm looking for a vectorized way to now have this as the new DataFrame:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
    X  Weight   Mult  SumWeight     NewCol
1  10     100   1000        800  32.142857
2  20     200   4000        800  37.500000
3  35     500  17500        800  75.000000
```

Comment: Since `df['SumWeight']` is a constant, you can move the call to `sum` onto `df['Mult']` and then it becomes easy: `df['Mult'].sum() / (df['Weight'].sum() - df['Weight'])`. This is really weird though. Are you sure these are the numbers you want?

Comment: That works! There are 5 other steps to get my final answer, but I was trying to figure out why I couldn't get the vectorized approach for the last step. Dumb, but that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!